# Javascript uncommon errors I get from my nodejs index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I don't understand how am getting this errors from running a javascript index.js file,
my project is a firebase functions and this is errors come from the nodejs index.js script, I use visual studio as ide.

```
   3:1   error  Expected space or tab after '//' in comment           spaced-comment
   4:1   error  Expected space or tab after '//' in comment           spaced-comment
  13:1   error  This line has a length of 126. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len
  13:89  error  Missing semicolon                                     semi
  17:16  error  Strings must use doublequote                          quotes
  17:68  error  Missing trailing comma                                comma-dangle
  21:1   error  Missing JSDoc comment                                 require-jsdoc
  21:18  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  22:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4          indent
  26:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4          indent
  26:5   error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead              no-var
  26:17  error  Multiple spaces found before 'req'                    no-multi-spaces
  27:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4          indent
  27:5   error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead              no-var
  28:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4          indent
  28:5   error  Expected space(s) after "if"                          keyword-spacing
  28:14  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  29:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8          indent
  29:28  error  Trailing spaces not allowed                           no-trailing-spaces
  30:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4          indent
  31:4   error  Newline required at end of file but not found         eol-last

✖ 21 problems (21 errors, 0 warnings)
  19 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-07T04_32_11_868Z-debug.log
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

Comment: These are all eslint errors... not syntax errors or runtime errors, but deviations from recommended best practices for code formatting.

Comment: Yeah, these are lint errors. Can you post a copy of the project package.json?

Comment: I see that you are using firebase functions for your project,Node.js runtime as an environment and using Javascript for composing the functions. I am assuming, to set up firebase CLI you must have ran the following commands:
1. npm install -g firebase-tools
2. firebase login. After a successful login, you went to the project directory and executed 
3. firebase init functions.
What did you say to each of the prompts when you did firebase init? Please help me reproduce the exact steps.
It would be helpful if you could  add your package.json file too.

Answer (score 4):

Change
`"lint": "eslint ."`
to
`"lint": "eslint"`
in the file `package.json` inside functions folder of your project

Comment: ```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  }
```

Comment: change to 
"scripts": { "lint": "eslint", "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions", "shell": "firebase functions:shell", "start": "npm run shell", "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions", "logs": "firebase functions:log" }